# Use of Mutex hangs the program

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex

I am trying to learn concurrency programming in C++.

I implemented a basic stack class with push(), pop(), top() and empty() methods.

I created two threads and both of them will try to access the top element and pop it until the stack gets empty.

First, I tried to implement it without using a mutex, and the output was gibberish and in the end resulting in *segfault*, which was expected as the operations were not atomic so the data race was inevitable.

So I tried to implement it with a mutex, and the program was hanging without even giving any output because of not unlocking the mutex.

Now, I have used a mutex locking+unlocking sequence properly, my program is giving correct output as desired, But afterwards the program is hanging -- could be possibly due to threads are still in execution or control is not reaching to the main thread?.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
std::mutex mtx;
std::mutex a_mtx;


class MyStack
{
    std::vector<int> stk;
public:
    void push(int val) {
        stk.push_back(val);
    }

    void pop() {
        mtx.lock();
        stk.pop_back();
        mtx.unlock();
    }

    int top() const {
        mtx.lock();
        return stk[stk.size() - 1];
    }

    bool empty() const {
        mtx.lock();
        return stk.size() == 0;
    }
};

void func(MyStack& ms, const std::string s)
{
    while(!ms.empty()) {
        mtx.unlock();
        a_mtx.lock();
        cout << s << " " << ms.top() << "\n";
        a_mtx.unlock();
        mtx.unlock();
        ms.pop();
    }

    //mtx.unlock();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    MyStack ms;

    ms.push(3);
    ms.push(1);
    ms.push(4);
    ms.push(7);
    ms.push(6);
    ms.push(2);
    ms.push(8);

    std::string s1("from thread 1"), s2("from thread 2");
    std::thread t1(func, std::ref(ms), "from thread 1");
    std::thread t2(func, std::ref(ms), "from thread 2");

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout << "Done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I figured because once the stack was empty, I was not unlocking the mutex. So when I uncomment the commented line and run it, it gives gibberish output and segfault.

I don't know where I am doing a mistake. Is this the right way of writing a thread-safe stack class?

Comment: instead of manually calling `mtx.lock()`, wrap it in a RAII class - `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mtx);` It will guarantee correct locking and unlocking, even if something throws an exception. Also - it's 1 line shorter :). I think the bug is in `top()`, since you lock the mutex and **never** unlock it. Wrapping it in `std::lock_guard` should fix that

Comment: well, that's a good suggestion, but I want to know the cause why the above code is hanging? No, see the while loop, I am unlocking it over there. And unlocking the mutex over there does not seem to be of any use since the method returns and it goes into while loop.

Comment: The right way is probably to make the mutex a member of your thread-safe stack class instead of a global. Client code (like `func`) should never need to see, lock or unlock it directly, the stack class can just use it internally.

Comment: If you want to see why it's hanging, have you tried attaching a debugger and seeing what each thread is doing?

Comment: @SurajPal, I edited my comment. Refresh the page - my 2 last sentences should shine some light on the problem

Comment: Unmatched lock/unlock calls, that's why it hangs. Anyhow, the very approach is flawed: If you check whether it's empty (guarded with a mutex) and then assume anything after releasing the lock, your code is broken. Oh, btw, one more thing: If you use a mutex, always document which objects that mutex is supposed to guard. It forces you to think about that, which avoids errors.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt But because of return statement it won't reach the unlock statement, so no use of unlocking it over there. I am new to all this concurrency handling. Since I am learning I wanted to start with basics first. So my design may be flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it gives gibberish output and segfault.

**It will *still* potentially give you *segfault*** under the current synchronization scheme, even if you go with the suggested [RAII style locking](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) like this:

```
void pop() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };
    stk.pop_back();
}

int top() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };
    return stk[stk.size() - 1];
}

bool empty() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };
    return stk.size() == 0;
}
```

as **you are not taking care of the [race-condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software)** arising between two subsequent calls to these methods by different threads. For example, think of what happens when the stack has one element left and one thread asks if it's empty and gets a `false` and then you have a context switch and the other thread gets the same `false` for the same question. So **they're both racing for that `top()` and `pop()`**. While the first one already pops it and then the other one tries to `top()` it will do so in a situation where `stk.size() - 1` yields `-1`. Hence, you get a *segfault* for trying to access a non-existing negative index of the stack : (

> I don't know where I am doing a mistake. Is this the right way of
>   writing a thread-safe stack class?

No, this is not the right way, the mutex only guarantees that other threads locking on the same mutex cannot be currently running this same section of the code. If they get to the same section, they're blocked from entering it until the mutex is released. But **you are not locking at all between the call** to `empty()` and the rest of the calls. One thread gets to `empty()`, locks, gets the value, then releases it, and then the other thread is free to enter and query and may well get the same value. What's preventing it later to enter your call to `top()`, and what's preventing the first thread to already be after that same `pop()` at that time?

In these scenarios you need to be careful to see the full scope of what needs protection in terms of synchronicity. The thing broken here is called *atomicity*, which means the property of "not being able be cut in middle". As you can see [here it says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) that "*Atomicity is often enforced by mutual exclusion,*" -- as in by using mutexes, like you did. What was missing is that [it was grained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity_(parallel_computing)) too finely -- the "size of the atomic" operation was too small. You should have been protecting the entire sequence of `empty()`-`top()`-`pop()` as a whole, as we now realize we cannot separate any piece out of the three. In code it could look something like calling this inside of `func()` and printing to `cout` only if it returned `true`:

```
bool safe_pop(int& value)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };

    if (stk.size() > 0)
    {
        value = stk[stk.size() - 1];
        stk.pop_back();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Admittedly, this doesn't leave much for the parallel work here, but I guess it's a decent exercise in concurrency.

Comment: But doesn't that defy the point of having mutex. From what I am understanding is that when a mutex is locked all the code which is getting executed under that thread will keep executing until that mutex is unlocked and thread switching will still happen but it won't be able to access the resource. Whatever you are saying makes sense to me, but I am still a little bit confused. Can you give me a reference for how to design these data structures with concurrency in mind ?

Comment: @SurajPal I've edited to try answer this more clearly. Let me know if it requires further explanation.

Comment: Yeah, Now I understand where it was going wrong and producing segfault. Although I understood it now, I am still baffled over the fact that if this is not a way to write thread-safe stack class, then what is? I am marking this as accepted answer. Thanks for your help and pointing out the mistake :).

Comment: @SurajPal The correct way is seeing exactly what needs to be protected *as a whole*, which cannot be separated unsafely into smaller parts. I'll add another edit to elaborate about this.

Comment: @SurajPal You need functions that are safe to call. Your `pop` function can only be safely called if you know that the stack will be non-empty after the mutex is acquired. That makes it not a very useful function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If I understand what you mean then I this is what I meant in the last line in the answer. You reckon I should make it more explicit?

Answer (score 2):

One error is that `MyStack::top` and `MyStack::empty` it does not unlock the mutex.

Use `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` to unlock the mutex automatically and eliminate the risk of such accidental dead-locks. E.g.:

```
bool empty() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    return stk.empty();
}
```

And it probably needs to lock the mutex in `MyStack::push` as well.

---

Another error is that the locking at the method level is too fine grained and `empty()` followed by `top()` and `pop()` is not atomic.

Possible fixes:

```
class MyStack
{
    std::vector<int> stk;
public:
    void push(int val) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        stk.push_back(val);
    }

    bool try_pop(int* result) {
        bool popped;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            if((popped = !stk.empty())) {
                *result = stk.back();
                stk.pop_back();
            }
        }
        return popped;
    }
};

void func(MyStack& ms, const std::string& s)
{
    for(int top; ms.try_pop(&top);) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(a_mtx);
        cout << s << " " << top << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Sorry but I'm afraid this still leaves the race-condition in tact : (

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist Fixed now.

Comment: @SurajPal Added a solution for you.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Glad to see. Un-downvoted immediately.

Comment: Thanks, @MaximEgorushkin The mistake I was doing was pointed by SkepticalEmpiricist and I know now how to actually write a TS stack class.